# Doubt regarding Notations for potential difference in EMFs

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, voltage, notation

Possible source of confusion -For work done carrying a unit charge from Point 1 to Point 2, ie the Potential difference, is it

> Voltage, $(V_{21}\:)=V_2\:-V_1\:$

OR is it

> Voltage, $(V_{12}\:)=V_2\:-V_1\:$

Secondly, when we talk about the potential difference between $A$ and $B$, do we mean work done carrying a unit charge from  $A$ to $B$ or the other way round. Is it equal to $(V_{AB}\:)$ or $(V_{BA}\:)?$

if you answer these alone, I would be very grateful!

---

Longer story, aka the inspiration...

> ...The positive electrode has a potential difference $V_{+}\:$ $(V_{+}\:> 0)$ between itself and the electrolyte solution immediately adjacent to it marked A in the figure.  The negative electrode develops a negative potential $–V_{-}\:$ $(V_{-}\:> 0)$  relative to the electrolyte adjacent to it, marked as B in the figure. When there is no current, the electrolyte has the same potential throughout, so that the potential difference between P and N is $V_+\:-\left(-\:V_-\:\right) = V_+\:+\left(\:V_-\:\right)$ . This difference is called the electromotive force (emf) of the cell and is denoted by ε.

[image: Image of cell]

Can any one help me trace the path of the positive charge in this case and give a better definition of  $V_+$ and  $V_-$ in this case along with 2 things. The fact that both are defined as positive annoys me, maybe it could be a typo.

1. The path of the positive charge in those $V_-$ and $V_+$
2. Mathematical representation of in the form format $V_-$ = $V_{NB}$ =  $V_N$- $V_B$  or whatever is actually correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) I'd take $V_{21}$ to mean $V_2-V_1$, that is the potential of point 2 relative to point 1. But I think that the user of the $V_{21}$ notation ought to explain how he or she is using it – it's probably not wholly standard notation.

(b) I don't think that there's any agreed convention about the sense of "the potential difference between A and B". If I wanted to use the phrase I'd say something like "the potential difference between A and B is 6.0 V, with A at the higher potential."

(c) Perhaps your annoyance with the $V_-,\ V+$ notation might be lessened if you think about these as the *magnitudes* of the potential differences at the two electrodes.

Comment: interestingly i found this which says "The electric potential difference between points A and B, VB−VA is defined to be the change in potential energy of a charge q moved from A to B, divided by the charge." at [Physic Libretexts](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/07%3A_Electric_Potential/7.03%3A_Electric_Potential_and_Potential_Difference#:~:text=V%3DUq.&text=The%20electric%20potential%20difference%20between,(V)%20after%20Alessandro%20Volta.)

Comment: but my text book used the opposite definition, maybe there's  no convention yet

Comment: did you mean V12 the first time and V21 the second time? was it a typo (one big reason I am coming here, to know whether there is any typo in my tb)

Comment: (i) "'the electric potential difference between points A and B, VB−VA[,] is defined to be [...]'" Here, the sense of "the potential difference between A and B'' is made clear by the inclusion of $V_B-V_A$. The sentence would mean the same thing if "the potential difference between A and B'' were omitted. (ii) No, I meant that neither $V_{12}$ or $V_{21}$ has a meaning that can be taken for granted. I used $V_{21}$ as an example.